# Problem with margins in documentclass article and package graphicx

Tags: graphics, margins, article

I noticed that using the documentclass `article` and the package `graphicx` changes the displayed margins. Is that problem known and is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: the `graphicx` package does not alter the margins. Please edit your question with a complete (small) example showing the problem you see,

Answer (score 10):

`graphicx` (and some other packages like `hyperref` and `geometry`) actually *corrects* a problem. Without it it can happen that the pdf size shown by the pdf viewer is not equal to the internal `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`. `graphicx` sets `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` to avoid this problem. If you are getting the wrong page size, make sure that the option of the class actually reflects the page size you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh yes so it does:-) (well `pdftex.def` does at least) I'd forgotten it did that, who wrote that file......